# Show $u(x,y)$ has a harmonic conjugate iff it is harmonic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Given $u(x,y)$, show that there exists a $v(x,y)$ satisfying
\begin{equation} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},\quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\end{equation}
only if $u$ satisfies the Laplacian equation $u_{xx} + u_{yy}=0$.

I am sorry to bother you with this. I don't know what my professor is asking here. Could someone give me some direction on this?

Comment: Try taking derivatives of the above equations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to prove the two equations imply it solves Laplace's equation, then:
$$u_{xx}=(u_x)_x=v_{yx}, u_{yy}=(u_y)_y=(-v_x)_y=-v_{xy}$$
And so summing these up, and on the lenient condition that $v_{xy}=v_{yx}$:
$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=v_{yx}-v_{xy}=0$$

Comment: I think the _only if_ part is the tricky one.

Comment: @Aruralreader "P only if Q" is equivalent to "if P then Q". Showing the existence of the conjugate would be the trickier direction.

Comment: Very nice.  The shorter the sweeter.  Let me just clarify - the "lenient condition" to which you refer, would that be that the partial derivatives are commutative only if x and y are independent and do not depend on each other?

Comment: I have a follow up question.

Comment: I am further asked to find all V(x,y) satisfying the equations in the first part for $U(x,y)=3x^2y-y^3+4xy$. I took the partial derivatives and found that $U_{xx}=6y$ and $U_{yy}=-6y$. Thus making the above equations true. Then I worked to find all V.  Integrating appropriately, I found that $V=3xy^2+4y$ and $V=x^3-3xy^2+2x^2$ Can anyone confirm that I am correct? Noam M or A rural reader?